# Jupyter notebook can't find matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I try to run matplotlib in my virtual env, this is what I get.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d0b23255e9ca> in <module>()
      1 import cv2
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 #%matplotlib inline

ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

This is the output when I run, `pip3 install matplotlib`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in ./.envs/opencv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in ./.envs/opencv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in ./.envs/opencv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./.envs/opencv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./.envs/opencv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./.envs/opencv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you start your jupyter notebook? From virtual environment also?

Comment: `(opencv) username|~/Dropbox/code/pydev/cv|-->jupyter notebook open_cv_getting_started.ipynb `

Comment: @Psidom yes that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: What if you type `pip freeze`? Are both `Jupyter notebook` and `matplotlib` included in the list?

Comment: `cycler==0.10.0 matplotlib==2.0.0 numpy==1.12.0 pyparsing==2.1.10 python-dateutil==2.6.0 pytz==2016.10 six==1.10.0`

Comment: @Psidom pip freeze doesn't seem to have `jupyter notebook`

Comment: You need to install jupyter in the virtual environment as well. Otherwise jupyter notebook session will not be in the virtual environment.

Comment: @Psidom i did that, still get the same error.

Comment: A few things to check. `pip install jupyter`, `pip freeze` shows `matplotlib` and `jupyter`? And if so, restart `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: I did all that. Still can't seem to find matplotlib

Comment: You can make a new virtual environment and retest it. It doesn't seem like you have a lot of libraries installed, so should be fast to test. I don't see a reason why this should not work.

Comment: @Psidom makes sense, let me try that.